# Arguments not compatible when calling method when they are the exact same format as in method class

Tags: java

I am trying to use a method in a different class that requires `int[][][] table` as arguments but when i put in the arguments it doesn't compile and says that the method is not applicable for the type `int[][][]::table` but there is no "`::`" i'm not sure where this has come from.

This is the part where I am trying to call the method

```
static void printTableOf(FSAe A) 
{
    Utils.printTransitionTable(int[][][] table);
}
```

This is the method in the utils class file:

```
static void printTransitionTable(int[][][] table)
{
    if (table.length == 0) return;

    int columns = table[0].length;
    String[] labels = new String[columns];

    for (int i=0; i<labels.length; i++) {
            if (i == columns-1)
                labels[i] = "eps";
            else
                labels[i] = i+"";
    }
```

EDIT: here is the method that initializes table:

```
static int[][][] transitionTable(FSAe A)
    {
        int[][][] table = new int[A.numStates][A.alphabetSize+1][0]; 
        for (int i=0; i<A.delta.length; i++) 
        {
            int[] t = A.delta[i];
            if (t[1] > -1) 
            {  
                Utils.updateTable(table, t[0], t[1], t[2]);
            }
            else 
            {
                Utils.updateTable(table, t[0], t[2], t[4]);
            }
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is pretty straightforward. What you're trying to do is pass a local variable *declaration* to the `printTransitionTable` method.
You need to correctly declare and initialize the `table` variable.

```
static void printTableOf(final FSAe A)  {
    final int[][][] table = Utils.transitionTable(A);
    Utils.printTransitionTable(table);
}
```

Just for your knowledge, the `::` syntax is to indicate a `method reference` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)).

Comment: I've already initialized the table array in a different method above which i forgot to mention cause I didn't wanna spam code, anyways I've returned it from that method how do I use it in the method printtableof? sorry i'm a bit of a java noob

Comment: I've added it in EDIT for reference

Answer (score 2):

You use the data type when you *define* a method, but not when you *call* a method.  When calling a method you just pass it a parameter of that type:

```
Utils.printTransitionTable(table);
```

This assumes that somewhere (not shown in your method, so perhaps at the class level) you have a variable *called* `table` which is of type `int[][][]` that you're passing to this method call.

Comment: @Virolite: That error would imply that you don't have a `table` to pass to the method.  You'll need one.  Otherwise what would calling the method be meant to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Utils.printTransitionTable(table);` instead of `Utils.printTransitionTable(int[][][] table);`

Comment: thank you, I also need to initialize the table variable :)

Comment: You must have the array declared and initialised inside the method, or in the class field, before actually passing it to a function. Have you taken care of this?

Comment: yeah bro, I added the code in EDIT section in my original post